# ng-init not setting first select options in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, html-select

I have a simple select element and I am trying to initialize the value but for some reason it is failing, i.e. not taking the init value

### HTML

```
<select class="select-form-control"
    ng-model="lossGainProb"
    ng-options="item.display for item in possibility track by item.value" 
    ng-init="EventDetails.lossGainProb">
```

### JavaScript

```
$scope.possibility = [{
    display: '0%',
    value: 0
}, {
    display: '5%',
    value: 5
}];

$scope.EventDetails.lossGainProb = 5;
```

Comment: Try setting `$scope.EventDetails.lossGainProb = { value: 5 };`, and set `ng-model="EventDetails.lossGainProb"`.

Comment: but i added track by item.value, shouldn't this take care of it and not have to get the value property?

Comment: Nope; `track by` just specifies the `value` attribute of your options. You could alternatively do `$scope.eventDetails.lossGainProb = $scope.possiblity[1];`, but that's basically the same thing.

Comment: regardless i have tried both and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the given code I have created small working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amighty/4hw3t05z/13/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
<select class="select-form-control" ng-model="lossGainProb" 
  ng-options="item.value as item.display for item in possibility">
</select>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.possibility =[ {
            display : '0%',
            value : 0
        }, {
            display : '5%',
            value : 5
        }];

    $scope.lossGainProb = $scope.possibility[1].value;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work without using `ng-init` - initializing in the controller:

```
$scope.lossGainProb = {};
$scope.lossGainProb.value = 5;
```

`ng-init` should not be used if possible - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit.

Comment: Your edit won't work either. For the initial value to be bound properly it must be identically equal (`===`) to one of the option values. You would need to do something like `$scope.lossGainProb = $scope.possibility[0]`.

Comment: It does work, I tested in a plunker. Let me find it.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, the `track by` takes care of that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You need the tracked item for the list tracked by angular. Try this:

```
$scope.possibility = [{
    display: '0%',
    value: 0
}, {
    display: '5%',
    value: 5
}];

$scope.EventDetails.lossGainProb = $scope.possibility.filter(function(item){ return item.value === 5})[0];
```

Working Codepen http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/bpbMom

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes I see:

1. You are using `ngInit` incorrectly. It does not specify the initial binding for the `ngModel` directive, it is an expression which is evaluated against the scope after the scope is initialized. To specify initial model bindings, you need something like

   ```
   <select ng-init="lossGainProb = EventDetails.lossGainProb"></select>
   ```

   Another (better) approach is to specify this in your controller directly, like

   ```
   $scope.lossGainProb = $scope.EventDetails.lossGainProb;
   ```
2. Your `ngModel` is bound to the entire "possibility" object rather than just the `value` property. I am assuming that you want just the `value` to be your model value. In this case, you should set `ngOptions` like

   ```
   <select ng-options="item.value as item.display for item in possibility"></select>
   ```

   This specifies that `ngModel` should be bound to `item.value` with `item.display` being used as the label.

Putting these together, your `select` should look like

```
<select class="select-form-control"
    ng-model="lossGainProb"
    ng-options="item.value as item.display for item in possibility"
    ng-init="lossGainProb = EventDetails.lossGainProb">
</select>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxrECQirqkkjcBEyzN2P?p=preview) is a working Plunker.

Comment: still not working for me, exact same code works in this plunker, any other way to debug that you are aware of?

Comment: can you post a runnable example which reproduces the error?

Comment: no same is not working, thats why i asked if any way to debug problem

Comment: In the Plunker I added a `{{ lossGainProb }}` in the template so that I can see the current binding. You can also put a `$watch` on it. Anyway, I encourage you to provide more details about your setup. Obviously something is different in your case.

Comment: binding value is exactly same but still value is not picked in the dropdown. nothing really special about my setup simple page really

Answer (score 0):

an alternate approach would be this one:

```
<select class="select-form-control" ng-init="lossGainProb = possibility[1].value" ng-model="lossGainProb" ng-options="item.value as item.display for item in possibility"> </select>
```